# SharePoint online, document library, folders permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, folder, item-level-permissions

I have created a site in SharePoint online, I have also created 100 folders in default document library.
I want to give "user a" permission on 100th folder only, he should not be able to see all other folders. He should not also see more folder if I create.

Is it possible? Do I need to give him permission on site and document library as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes quite possible and easy!!

1. Open your Library where your 100th folder is there and select it.
2. Click share after you select your desired folder .
3. A popup comes , click on 'can edit'-->then on 'advanced' .
4. Stop inheriting permissions , remove if required and provide to the desired users.

Done!!

Comment: Ok, worked, What about OneDrive, If user sync the library, would he get folder he does not has access to?

Comment: No they wont be able to see other folders in which they don't have permissions , you can go ahead. i just now checked. PLease tick my answer or upvote if you found this useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible and the permission can only be granted to the folder you desire. This would be done by breaking the permission inheritance from the above level and assigning unique permission for the folder in question. However, for avoiding

- unnecessary end-user confusions with multiple "Sorry, you don't have access to this page" when the user attempts to move anywhere around the folder,
- possible layout issues with how the folder is displayed for the user, and
- permission management headache,

you *should not* do this.

Instead, *plan* and *implement* a structure for your document management so that the users *always* have a logical way to navigate upwards (i.e. from folder to parent library, from parent library to the site, etc.).

So,

> Do I need to give him permission on site and document library as well?

You don't have to, but you should.

Answer (score 0):

Though Breaking Inheritance at the 100th folder will solve your problem. It's not always suggestible solution to break the inheritance especially when you have huge number of folder.

That will create maintainability issues in future.

So Check multiple times before on why this is needed. Or you can implement better permission structure that will help you achieve this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all sites, lists, and libraries in a site collection inherit permissions settings from the site that is directly above them in the site hierarchy. This means a site inherits permissions from the root site of the site collection, and a sub site inherits permissions from its parent site. Folders, lists and documents inherit permissions from the site that contains them, and so on.

To assign unique permissions to a list, library, or survey, you have to first break permissions inheritance, then assign unique permissions. You can do all of this on the Permissions page. This article shows you how to get to the Permissions page and break inheritance, and then provides the steps to assign or change permissions.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-SharePoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782